# What can I do if invalid downvotes weren't reversed after flagging?

Tags: support, serial-voting

On May 3, four of my questions were downvoted within ten seconds of each other. When you add in that all of the questions are at least six months old with no other recent activity and none had been downvoted previously, I can't imagine any scenario where this is legitimate activity.

After ~28 hours, the votes hadn't been reversed automatically, so I custom flagged one of the questions with links to the others. The flag was marked as helpful...but now it's been another two days and the votes still haven't been reversed.

Do I have any other options at this point, or am I just out of luck?

Comment: Stack Overflow is nearly useless on this, frankly. On multiple occasions I've received multiple downvotes in quick succession, yet they've done nothing (even after me contacting them).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Site moderators automatically mark such flags helpful and then pass the issue on to the Community Modereration team as only they and Stack Overflow developers can do anything to reverse voting. This normally takes a while, particularly as they don't work weekends.

Comment: That makes sense, I didn't realize it was beyond the scope of normal moderators.

Comment: Moderators cannot see individual votes and do not have the ability to reverse them. That requires a Stack Exchange employee with database access. @John